# Without rephrasing the sentence, is there an idiom for inverting "He got X, Y but no Z"?

Tags: phrases

Here's the inclusive sentence:

> Then the merchant receives the order details containing the invoice, refund and cancellation.

Here's the exclusive version:

> Then the merchant receives the order details containing *no* invoice, *no* refund and *no* cancellation.

Is there an idiom for including only cancellation? Or is my only recourse to extend the sentence with "but it does contain the", which sound rather redundant.

Something like the following for example:

> Then the merchant receives the order details containing *no* invoice, *no* refund, *but* cancellation.

Comment: We generally put the positive thing or things first, then 'and' or 'but' followed by the negative things. "the merchant receives the order details containing cancellation and/but no invoice, refund or cancellation." We would use 'and' if the situation is routine and 'but' if the negative items were normally to be expected.

Comment: Then the merchant receives the order details containing no invoice, no refund, but **with the** cancellation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you provided is good if you add in a word or phrase that would make it flow better.

Depending on the context, you can try one of the following:

> Then the merchant receives the order details containing no invoice, no refund, but only a/the cancellation.

> Then the merchant receives the order details containing no invoice, no refund, but indeed a/the cancellation.

> Then the merchant receives the order details containing no invoice, no refund, but, fortunately, a/the cancellation.

> Then the merchant receives the order details containing no invoice, no refund, but instead, a/the cancellation.

Comment: D'oh, sometimes the answer is just right in front of you.